# onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() fires for intermediate size changes

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Having played with the onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() function a bit, it seems that it is fired even for intermediate steps in a resizing from one size to another.

So, say the user resizes the widget from 4x1 to 2x1, the method fires first when the bounding box hits 3x1, and then again when it gets to 2x1, in both cases before the user has actually confirmed the new size.

Is there any way of getting such a method to fire only once, when the user has actually confirmed the final size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fear it's not possible to get the system tell you that kind of information. You might have to implement some custom solution of your own. AFAIK, there is no system callback that denotes the end of the re-sizing event.